# mid-roll video ads becoming post-roll video ads

Tags: jwplayer, ads, ova

i've try mid-roll video ads with this ova code : 

               
                  '.$uri.' Video Ads
                
               
                   {
                    "ads": 
                        {
                            "controls": {
                                   "skipAd": {
                                      "enabled": true,
                                      "showAfterSeconds": 15
                                   }
                              },

```
                        "servers": [
                               {
                                  "type": "OpenX",
                                  "apiAddress":  "http://ads.viva.co.id/ads/www/delivery/fc.php",
                                    "allowAdRepetition": true
                               }
                        ],
                        "schedule": [
                           "position": "mid-roll",
                           "startTime": "00:00:10",
                           "zone": "349",
                           "playOnce": false,
                           "notice": {
                           "show": false
                        ]},
                    "debug": {
                          "debugger": "firebug",
                          "levels": "fatal, config, vast_template, vpaid, http_calls"
                    }

                }
           </ova.json>
        </config>
```

but mid-roll becoming post-roll ads, it show after main video play, how can i fix this ?

Comment: Please provide a link.

Comment: sorry ethan, i don't know how to provide my code as a link, but, have you a suggestion for me, why my mid-roll ads become post-roll ads ?

Comment: The JW Player is meant to be embedded into a website. So, what is the site...

Answer (score -1):

once again, this my ova code

```
<config>
   <ova.title>
   Video Ads
    </ova.title>    
    <ova.json>
       {    
        "ads": 
            {
            "controls": {
                       "skipAd": {
                      "enabled": true,
                      "showAfterSeconds": 15
                       }
              },

            "servers": [
                       {
                        "type": "OpenX",
                        "apiAddress":  "http://ads.../ads/www/delivery/fc.php",
                        "allowAdRepetition": true
                       }
                    ],
            "schedule": [
                       "position": "mid-roll",
                       "startTime": "00:00:10",
                        "zone": "349",
                       "playOnce": false,
                       "notice": {
                       "show": false
                        ]},
            "debug": {
          "debugger": "firebug",
                      "levels": "fatal, config, vast_template, vpaid, http_calls"
                    }

                }
</ova.json>
</config>
```

Answer (score -1):

and this my jwplayer code :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo kone_url('appaux-js', 'swfobject-5.8.js');?>"></script>
<div id="video_iims2014" style="margin: 0px auto; padding-top: 3px; overflow: hidden;">
</div> 
<script type='text/javascript' src="<?php echo kone_url('appaux-js', 'jwplayer-5.10.js');?>"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
  jwplayer("video_iims2014").setup({
          'id': 'playerID',
          'width': '663',
          'height': '390',
          'controlbar.position': 'bottom',    
          'plugins' : '<?php echo kone_url("appaux-swf", "ova-jw.swf")?>',
          'config' : '<?php echo $config; ?>',            
              'modes': [
                      {
                       type: 'flash', 
                       src: '<?php echo kone_url("appaux-swf", "jwplayer-5.10.swf")?>',
                       config: {
                       'image' : "<?=thumbImage(array('path'=>$videos[0]['path_thumbnail'], 'width'=>'663', 'height'=>'382', 'type' => 'videos'));?>",
                       'file': "<?php echo kone_url('media-videos', $videos[0]['path']);?>",
                            }
                        },
                        {
               type: 'html5',
                    config: {
                           'image' : "<?=thumbImage(array('path'=>$videos[0]['path_thumbnail'], 'width'=>'663', 'height'=>'382', 'type' => 'videos'));?>",
                           'file': "<?php echo kone_url('media-videos').$videos[0]['path'];?>",
                            }
                        },
                        {type: 'download' }
                    ]
                });
            </script>
```